# CollectionView in a TabbedPage not displaying data Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview, tabbedpage

This is the background.  I have a TabbedPage view that holds 3 ContentPage type Views.  The middle tab is a Content Page that has a CollectionView that is bound to an ObservableCollection in the corresponding ViewModel.

Here's the problem.  When I click the middle tab, there is no data being shown in the CollectionView.  I ran debug with breakpoints and I can see that the underlying ObservableCollection has been populated when the Main TabbedPage was instantiated.  HOwever there is no data being shown in the tab itself.

```
If I hit 'Save' on the View in VS, the simulator then refreshes and correctly shows the data.  What am I missing?  Should I be calling some sort of refresh method when tabs are clicked?  Just started working on Xamarin.Forms and teaching myself, so please be gentle.
```

EDIT:  Sorry Code added below:  I do see the EmptyView string being displayed until I go back into VS and hit Save on the View.

This is my View:

```
<RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" Command="{Binding RefreshCategoriesCommand}">  
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories}" 
                            EmptyView="No products found"
                            SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding GetCategoryDetailCommand}" 
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="15" Margin="0,10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Source="{Binding image.src}"
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60"
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding name}"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" 
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
```

ViewModel code:

```
 public CategoryGroupViewModel(IDialogService dialogService, INavigationService navigationService, IConnectionService connectionService, IWooCommerceRepository wooCommerceRepository)
        : base(dialogService, navigationService, connectionService)
    {
        _wooCommerceRepository = wooCommerceRepository;
        GetCategoryDetailCommand = new Command(OnGetCategoryDetail);
        RefreshCategoriesCommand = new Command(OnRefreshCategories);

        GetCategories();
    }

 private async void GetCategories()
    {
        try
        {
            var categories = await _wooCommerceRepository.GetProductCategories();
            ProductCategories = new ObservableCollection<ProductCategory>((IEnumerable<ProductCategory>)categories);
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _dialogService.ShowDialog("Oops we hit an error " + ex.Message + "  " + ex.ToString(), "Error", "OK");
        }

    }
```

Thank you

Comment: how can we possibly help you if you don't post any code?

Comment: Please show us relevant codes. Does your data binding successfully?